# showing two tables concurrently that are hidden by ckicking on img

Tags: javascript, html

is there any solution to clicking one image and showing two tables?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function setTable(what){
    if(document.getElementById(what).style.display=="none"){
    document.getElementById(what).style.display="block";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById(what).style.display=="block"){
    document.getElementById(what).style.display="none";
    }
    }
    </script>

    <img src="../../images/p1.gif" onclick="setTable('table5');">
    <table id='table5' border="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
    ......
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table id='table6' border="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
    ......
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have to remember that an ID is supposed to be unique JS will often fail with a duplicated ID as the script doesn't know what ID to process, for this reason class methods are best used. Unfortunately my example code that I know works is at work (it's 2:25am here) so another programmer will need to help you today. A side tip for the future, try breaking down your sentences so they aren't so long without, it will be easier for us to understand how we can help you. Have a good one and good luck mate :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to have multiple objects with the same ID in the same web page.  Give the second table a different id and then show both of them separately.

Change the code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setTable(what){
    if(document.getElementById(what).style.display=="none"){
    document.getElementById(what).style.display="block";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById(what).style.display=="block"){
    document.getElementById(what).style.display="none";
    }
    }
</script>

    <img src="../../images/p1.gif" onclick="setTable('table5'); setTable('table6');">
    <table id='table5' border="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
    ......
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table id='table6' border="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
    ......
    </tr>
    </table>
```

In the click handler, you call setTable twice - once for each ID.
In the second table, you change the ID

Or, you could put both tables in a div and hide/show that div.

Comment: I have one just image I can't insert another image